# Symfony2 embedded forms with the "child" entity assigned in a dynamic way

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a Project entity which is tied to a Tolerance entity.

On the surface the Project has just one Tolerance so it seems a one-to-one, but in practice I want to keep track of all the changes in the Tolerance entity. To do so, every time a project is saved, if the tolerance entity fields changed I want to save a new "version" of the tolerance, recording the timestamp and who did the change.

In visualization, every time a user sees a Project, or edit it, will see the last version of the Tolerance attached.

The problem is that I have no clue how to manage the thing from the point of view of the form.

As the Tolerance entity can be referred to other stuff other than a project, I have ProjectTolerance extending Tolerance.

This is the Project entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ProjectRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="projects")
 */
class Project
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $name;
    //other fields
```

This is the base Tolerance:

```
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
class Tolerance
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $risk;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $scope;

    // other fields        

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $timestamp;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     */    
    protected $changedBy;    


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->timestamp = new \DateTime();
    }
```

And this is the extension:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ProjectToleranceRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="project_tolerances")
 */
class ProjectTolerance extends BaseTolerance
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project")
     */    
    protected $project;

    /**
     * Set project
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Project $project
     * @return ProjectTolerance
     */
    public function setProject(\AppBundle\Entity\Project $project = null)
    {
        $this->project = $project;

        return $this;
    }
```

Do I need to specify the relationship in the Project entity as a oneToMany relationship as well? I imagine that if I do so I need to tweak the "getTolerance" so that it gets the last version of the tolerance...

How do I manage the forms?

EDIT: here is the creation of the form as it is now (inside the controller, I'll take it out as an independent form type):

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($project)
->add('name', 'text')
->add('approach', 'text')
->add('background', 'text')
->add('scope', 'text')
->add('scopeExclusions', 'text')
->add('interfaces', 'text')
->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create project'))
->getForm();
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

What I'm missing is probably something like:

```
$builder->add('tolerances', 'collection', array('type' => new ProjectToleranceFormType(), 'allow_add'    => true, 'label' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    ))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's [One-To-Many relation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table). You have to add next to your models classes:

```
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
class Project
{
   ...

   /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="Tolerance",
     *     mappedBy="project",
     *     orphanRemoval=true
     * )
     **/
    private $tolerances;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tolerances= new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    ...
    public function getTolerances()
    {
        return $this->tolerances;
    }

    public function addTolerance(Tolerance $tolerance)
    {
        $this->tolerances->add($tolerance);
        $tolerance->setProject($this);
    }

    public function removeTolerance(Tolerance $tolerances)
    {
        $this->tolerances->removeElement($tolerances);
        $tolerances->setProject(null);
    }
}

/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
class Tolerance
{
   ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="tolerances")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $project;
    ...
    public function getProject()
    {
        return $this->project;
    }

    public function setProject(Project $project = null)
    {
        $this->project= $project;
    }
}
```

Next step when you submit the project form then set the tolerance data.

Read more about [doctrine relations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html).

For createdAt and UpdatedAt fields you can use [Timestampable Doctrine Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html).

Comment: Thank you, I think it's a start, but this would be the vanilla solution in case of a standard one to many, but in my case I need a one to many behaving as a one to one. I need a getTolerance (note without the "s") that retrieves just the last Tolerance applied.

Comment: The tolerances are stored in an [ArrayCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.2/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html), so just call: $project -> getTolerances() -> last();

Comment: Would you be so kind to share how I could write the formBuilder in order to tell it that it has to get the last one in visualization? It's the only missing piece